# CKEditor setData with rails variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'm trying to auto-populate the value of a CKEditor textarea with text from a rails variable, but I can only get plain text to populate.  The user pastes a link into a textfield, then the controller uses nokogiri to parse the link and a js partial to autopopulate the CKEditor textarea.

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@link_post, :url => link_posts_path, html: { multipart: true }, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :url, placeholder: "Type or paste a url" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, :class => 'ckeditor form-control', placeholder: "Add a caption" %>
  </div>

<%= f.submit id: "submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

_preview.js.erb

```
CKEDITOR.instances.link_post_content.setData( "text" );
```

If I just put a string in single or double quotes in the place of "text", it autofills the CKEditor area just fine.  But if I try to do `CKEDITOR.instances.link_post_content.setData( "#{@summary}" );` or `CKEDITOR.instances.link_post_content.setData( "<%= @summary %>" );` where @summary is a string that prints fine with `puts @summary` or appends as expected to any div from the js partial.  Is there a syntax for this?  I've also tried setting a js variable (`var text = "#{@summary}"`) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with `CKEDITOR.instances.link_post_content.setData( "<%== @text %>" );`, needed `<%==` instead of `<%=`